# Ionic swipe gesture not working on phone

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, gesture, ionic3

I try to do a swipe gesture to switch between tabs. I want the gesture will work on all over the screen. I catch the swipe movement in

```
<ion-content (swipe)="swipeEvent($event)">
```

And the swipeEvent funtion is

```
swipeEvent(e) {
  if(e.direction == '2'){
     this.navCtrl.parent.select(2);
  }
  else if(e.direction == '4'){
     this.navCtrl.parent.select(0);
  }
}
```

It works fine in browser. But when I build it in a phone the gesture has no effect.
Is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just solved it by adding a div with 100% height and width.

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div (swipe)="swipeEvent($event)" style="position: absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;">
    <ion-item>

    </ion-item>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: There is **no difference** the suggested solution by me and your one here.You too just did the same thing here.You removed the `(swipe)` from the `ion-content` and put that into inner `div`.No difference.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution from Ionic team member: [**See this too**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/9762#issuecomment-272538109).

> It's not really recommended to use swipe gestures on the main content.
>   Since ion-content is a input for gestures anyways (scrolling and such)
>   it having swipe on it can just cause confusion. Instead, putting the
>   event handler on a child element works fine.

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card (swipe)="swipeEvent($event)">
    <ion-item>

    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: but I need the gesture on all over the screen.

Comment: That is by design.Sorry, you can't.

Comment: Try like this.Hope this will catch the swipe left event.`<ion-content (swipeleft)="swipeLeftEvent($event)">`

Comment: Just solved it by adding a div with 100% height and width. Thank you, your answer helped explains why I got the bug in the first place.

Comment: I tried the (swipeleft) didn't work. It's all about the <ion-content> tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151428/discussion-between-tontus-and-sampath).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use `(swipe)` on the custom component and solved the problem by adding a `display:block` to the component style.